Why does fdisk create a 512B partition when I enter +256K?
I am trying to create a partition of 256KB on my flash device. I begin by entering the default values for the partition number (1) and first sector (2048). However, when I enter "+256K" for the last sector, it creates a partition of size 512 B. Can you please help me understand why this is happening? I believe I am entering the right input for a 256KB partition according to documentation and tutorials.
Here are the console commands and output:
Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-31116254, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-31116254, default 31115263): +256K

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 512 B.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.84 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Disk model: STORAGE DEVICE  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5112D407-F33A-446F-B778-3DE3AB57B804

Device     Start   End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048  2048       1  512B Linux filesystem


By default fdisk aligns all partitions to the nearest grain and in this case it unfortunately means the partition end is aligned down and it results in a 1 sector long partition:
8673: libfdisk:      CXT: [0x55f20b20d4c0]: 2048 in range <2048..200704> aligned to 2048
8673: libfdisk:      GPT: new partition: partno=0, start=2048, end=2048, size=1

(fdisk output with LIBFDISK_DEBUG=all). Unfortunately partition alignment with very small partitions isn't always working as expected, you can read more about this alignment in the libfdisk documentation.
If you want to prevent libfdisk from doing this you need to specify exact size you want in sectors, in your case 512 (+511 to get 512 sectors):
Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (2048-204766, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-204766, default 202751): +511

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 256 KiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/loop0: 100 MiB, 104857600 bytes, 204800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5B936EAF-D33A-4526-9BBC-DD5E8B88E705

Device       Start   End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop0p1  2048  2559     512  256K Linux filesyste


Nice find. Just from looking at the source code, I didn't expect +512 to work either, so I didn't even try.

Thank you for your help Voljtech. Can I please know what you mean by "nearest grain"?

"The grain is usually 1MiB (or more for devices where optimal I/O is greater than 1MiB)." (from the libfdisk documentation I linked in the answer)
So in your case it means rounding down to 1 MiB (2048 sectors) which is also the partition start.

(+511 to get 512 sectors) Yet another reason I despise fdisk (in util-linux): while it can and should see +num as a size in sectors, the maintainer insisted that it "makes sense" to see it as "End minus Start".

@VojtechTrefny where optimal I/O is greater than 1MiB Btw pretty much all UAS bridges for (S)ATA drives on the market for some reason advertise a  hardcoded optimal I/O size of 65535 (0xffff) in their firmware, so things would be awful when fdisk try to be "smart". (Not to mention that it make all these "corrections" in such an implicit manner that you could end up realizing that things were done wrong only when it's too late.)

@Tom Yan It does see +511 as a size in sectors. 2048 plus the (size of) 511 sectors gives sector 2559, the correct last sector. I think you mean it should ask for the size of the partition instead of the last sector of the partition where one would put 512 to create a partition of 512 sectors.

@ikegami 512 (without +) is an LBA like 2559 (e.g. which sector is the last sector). Size in sectors is size of partition (in sectors, instead of in KiB or so). +511 is considered by fdisk the number of "steps" to get from from a starting LBA to an ending LBA, like if you see the LBAs / sectors as "bars", the number is seen as the number of "gaps" between the "bars" in concern (while the size is really the number of "bars"), and that's silly, because + should consistently make the number that follows considered as size, regardless whether the unit is sector or KiB or MiB.

@Tom Yan, + refers to addition or additional sectors here. It's asking for the last sector of the partition, so 2559 or +511, since 2048 + 511 = 2559. It would be very confusing if + didn't mean addition here.

@ikegami not at all to me, just like I wouldn't want / expect +1M to give me a partition of the size of 2049 sectors (the one starting sector "added" with another 1MiB 512-byte sectors). You don't need to explain to me what it refers to, my point was exactly what it refers at the moment makes no practical sense, and under no circumstances it could make anyone's life easier (because even if you literally need a partition to end at a certain LBA, you would be given the LBA -- instead of the number of "steps" you need to get there.)

@ikegami To put it in another way, the definition of the End sector (LBA) itself has never been Start sector (LBA) + size in sectors, regardless of whether the size is entered directly or "derived", but Start sector + size - 1, because Start sector itself is not "sizeless". To be blunt, if anyone finds it confusing, that's really like "their own problem". (On the other hand, it's non-sensical when one is required to think like "so I want a partition of 512-sector long, so I need to enter + and the desired size minus one, because the Start sector is already one sector long.")

I'm not sure if this is a bug or intentional, however it appears to be the case that fdisk enforces alignment when using GPT partition table and relative values (+,-). See relevant source code on Github.
You can kind of see what's going on when you run fdisk with debug options (produces a LOT of noise):
# FDISK_DEBUG=all LIBFDISK_DEBUG=all fdisk /dev/loop0
[…]
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-20446, default 18431): +256K
142514: fdisk:      ASK: user's reply: >>>+256K<<< [rc=0]
142514: fdisk:      ASK: parsed size: 262144
142514: fdisk:      ASK: final offset: 2560 [sig: +, power: 1, relative]
142514: libfdisk:      ASK: [0x57622c6db250]: do_ask done [rc=0]
142514: libfdisk:      CXT: [0x57622c698460]: 2048 in range <2048..16384> aligned to 2048
142514: libfdisk:      GPT: new type: af3dc60f-8384-7247-8e79-3d69d8477de4
142514: libfdisk:      GPT: new partition: partno=0, start=2048, end=2048, size=1
[…]

In case of 2048 +256K, it first comes out correctly as 2560, but then fdisk_align_lba_in_range(cxt, lba=2560, start=2048, stop=…) snaps it back to 2048, resulting in a single sector partition. Forcing it to use 2560 as minimum value, it instead jumps to 4096, resulting in a 1 MiB partition.
Technically the CXT: debug message in the output above is wrong, it prints lba after it has already been modified. It should say 2560 in range <2048..16394> aligned to 2048.
2048, 4096, 2560 are all too large by 1, this surplus sector is substracted after the alignment step.
tl;dr: Use absolute values instead. Those still seem to work for now. Or, consider making MiB aligned partitions even if you don't need a whole MiB.

This is very insightful, thank you for investigating this issue! I will be sure to use the debug options next time.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or intentional It's purely just dumb. There's no legit reason to "align" the size -- it could totally align only the default start in each new partition command prompt like g(ptf)disk does.

@TomYan Microsoft claimed back in the day that a lot of "advanced format" disks have performance issues when the offsets are odd numbers (such as the 63 in the old system). Given their commitment to compatibility, there's probably some truth to that. Fdisk might have just followed the way Vista dealt with those.

@Luaan His point was aligning the start of the partition is important as it affects every single write. What effect is aligning the end going to have?

I maintain what I replied (and was deleted 12 hours ago, with a false accusation of "rant". It makes no sense to align partitions to 1MiB boundaries and not extend them to the end of the boundary, just to result in a 1 sector partition containing only a single partition boot sector, and no space left at all for any content. Partition sizes must be also aligned to fit to the end of partitions. For smaller partitions, intended just to emulate the space of old floppies, it just makes sense to just use a file within another larger filesystem to get the space you need as a "virtual" filesystem.

So this is a bug of libfdisk, if it reduces the requested volume size so that it becomes unusable for any kind storage. The fault being that it rounds to the nearest boundary, but even fails, reserving a minimum 1 sector size, which does not even align the end, but still reserves 1MiB on disk for... nothing usable by any filesystem (except 2047 "reserved" sectors at end, that could eventually be used to store malware data in a partition mostly invisible with most tools, as you can't mount it for normal live and usage with some standard filesystem-level security).

Aligning size sometimes matters, for example with LUKS. Often its just a space/efficiency question; like LVM can't use partial extents and will just list it as "not usable" in pvdisplay.
